# WPF Download File Applications for multiple files

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

Firstly let me tell you that I searched in the internet, but could not get any help.
I need to develop an application where I need to show currently how many files are downloading and every files name, progress along with we have the option to cancel the download whenever we want. For better understanding I have attached an image the overall UI design. But I have a doubt that how at runtime I will keep appending files in the download Window? Suppose I am downloading a file, now after sometime i will start another file to download. How will I add that Download in the same window. Any ideas and codes and help would be a great help. [image: Download Window]

The data I will be getting from a cache in our application. the file name and how much bytes downloaded and total size everything is stored in the  cache, but run time keep adding/removing the download Window is an issue. Help please

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look on [WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx). Your question seems too broad to answer here.

Comment: What have you tried? What are some of your ideas? Which problems specifically do you need help with? You need to show that you've at least tried something before anyone here can help you.

Comment: Yes, surely I understand that. I will definitely update my post with source codes and examples and what Problem I am facing.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an ObservableCollection to store the download information (file name, progress, etc.), then create a container (e.g. ListView) with an DataTemplate and then bind the collection to the control.

When you want add another file to the downloades files list, you simply add it to the ObservableCollection and it will automatically show up on the UI.

Comment: Thanks, I will surely take a note of this and implement in that way. Thanks for the help.